# Finding all roots of $z^4-4z^3+9z^2-4z+8$

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

I need to know all the roots of $z^4-4z^3+9z^2-4z+8$. I know only one root: z=i. Is there an **easy** way to find the 3 roots that are unknown?

thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the complex conjugate of $i$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**

When you have complex roots (**of real polynomials** as DonAntonio pointed out in his comment), they come by conjugate pairs : so, if $z=i$ is a root, $z=-i$ is another one. So, doing the long division, you are left with a quadratic in $z$.

Comment: @DonAntonio. You are pefectly right (as usual) ! I edit my answer quoting you. Cheers.

Comment: You are very welcome ! Don't forget this property. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: There is also the conjugate root $-i$ and you can divide by $x^2+1$ and get the factorization $(x^2+1)(x^2-4x+8).$

Answer (score 2):

We know two roots, $i$ and $-i$. Their sum is $0$ and their product is $1$.

The sum of **all** the roots of the quartic is the negative of the coefficient of $x^3$, that is $4$. The product of all the roots is $8$.

Thus the sum of the two missing roots is $4$, and their product is $8$. So the missing roots are the roots of $z^2-4z+8=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Complex conjugate root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem),  the other root is $-i$

So, the rest two roots will be available from $$\frac{z^4-4z^3+9z^2-4z+8}{(z-i)(z+i)}=0$$

Comment: One more you won by a few seconds. Cheers :)